# Using pycharm to debug django application with python3 as docker container within a vagrant instance

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm, vagrant

I set up an ubuntu vagrant instance as virtual machine and installed docker in it. I also have python as docker container within vagrant instance. Is there anyway to debug django application using pycharm directively with python in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Vagrant is just a frontend to several virtualization systems and the backend is the important part for the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible indeed but I very much doubt you really need to use such a complex setup. Isn't it possible to run Docker on your OS directly?

Anyway, if you are confident. PyCharm at the moment does not "natively" support  remote Docker daemon usage, so you have to tweak a bunch of options manually. I wrote a detailed guide in the dedicated ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33489 Remote machine in your case is a Vagrant VM.

P.S. Please vote for the PY-33489 ticket if you want such support in PyCharm simplified.